# EnableCacheVisualization not working

Tags: silverlight

I know I've made this work before but now I don't know what I am doing wrong.

- I create a new hosted Silverlight application.
- I added a button object on the MainPage.xaml setting CacheMode="BitmapCache"
- I edited my default.apsx file to add the following lines to the silverlight object tag :

  `<param name="EnableCacheVisualization" value="true" />`

  `<param name="EnableGPUAcceleration" value="true" />`

  `<param name="EnableFrameRateCounter" value="true" />`

But I cannot see neither the FrameRateCounter or the CacheVisualization... What am I doing wrong here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you both for your help, but I got my answer...  It is really stupid, but those functions are not working with "**Windows Server 2008**"!!!  I changed my workstation recently and wasn't aware of that.

got my answer here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833062(v=VS.95).aspx

> Hardware acceleration is only enabled on Windows Vista, Windows 7, and
>   Windows XP. On Windows XP NVidia, ATI, Intel cards with a driver date
>   post November 2004 is required for hardware acceleration.

Comment: Very interesting!  However, that should not prevent the framerate counters from showing - there must be something else going on, no?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the Web Application is set as the startup project and that the Default.aspx is its start page.  Also check that your app is compiling without error in some cases VS will just continue and run the original XAP when compiling a new one fails.

Comment: Good guess, bu there must be something else wrong in because I already checked all that. I even checked the HTML Source of my default.aspx (when running) and the params are there! My xap compile just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have some startup code somewhere that sets those options back to False?

Try adding a button which shows the value of `System.Windows.Interop.Settings.EnableCacheVisualization`.

Otherwise, can you post your html page source?